# Find sum of data from a query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i find the sum of the results for the below query

```
 select DATEPART(month,date) as month ,sum(volume) as Total_Volume
from    traffic_data_replica
where   DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' and DATENAME(year,date)=2013 
group by DATEPART(month,date)
order by DATEPART(month,date);
```

In short, sum of the results returned by the above query

Comment: What do you mean by sum of results? Do you need the number of records returned by the query or the sum of Total_Volume?

Comment: what is error in query?

Comment: The above query will return results in rows , i want the sum of it

Comment: Do you mean the number of rows returned?

Comment: If you want sum of all Total_Volume that you receive on rows in your current query, you can use: SELECT SUM(Total_Volume) FROM (select DATEPART(month,date) as month ,sum(volume) as Total_Volume
from    traffic_data_replica
where   DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' and DATENAME(year,date)=2013 
group by DATEPART(month,date)
order by DATEPART(month,date)) AS Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sum of all Total_Volume that you receive on rows in your current query, you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Volume) 
FROM (
    select DATEPART(month,date) as month ,
    sum(volume) as Total_Volume 
    from traffic_data_replica 
    where 
    DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' 
    and DATENAME(year,date)=2013 
    group by DATEPART(month,date) 
    order by DATEPART(month,date)
) AS Data
```

If you want count of rows that you receive on rows in your current query, you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    select DATEPART(month,date) as month ,
    sum(volume) as Total_Volume 
    from traffic_data_replica 
    where 
    DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' 
    and DATENAME(year,date)=2013 
    group by DATEPART(month,date) 
    order by DATEPART(month,date)
) AS Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  select DATEPART(month,date) as month ,sum(volume) as Total_Volume
from    traffic_data_replica
where   DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' and DATENAME(year,date)=2013 
group by DATEPART(month,date)
order by DATEPART(month,date)
) AS subquery;
```